# Manage windows 2008 server from linux

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-access

Is the way to manage windows from linux terminal using only base windows soft? E.g. how can send files from linux or run some script? Install ssh server on windows unfortunately not suitable.

Comment: If installing an ssh server is not an option and you do not want to RDP maybe [the 3rd option in this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/638661/41695) is the way to go.

Comment: Filburt, PowerShell Web Access works only for Win Server 2012 R2, but is it possible use rdp only by terminal?

Comment: True, if you're stuck with Win 2008 and no ssh then your only hope could be [Pash](https://github.com/Pash-Project/Pash).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand, how pash can helps me. The goal isn't run powershsell scripts under lunux, but managing remote windows server 2008 using linux (bash scripts).

Comment: Then I don't understand how you expect to run bash scripts without running an according service on your windows box. PowerShell Remoting is available for Win 2008 and pash (hopefully) will enable you to remotely run ps scripts.